# Doctrine,Typo3 Flow : unable to get delete cascade to work

Tags: php, doctrine, typo3

I have a model which gives me an error when if i try to delete the entry from the database (due to constraint violation) .

The error message is:

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM pits_docmanager_domain_model_role WHERE id = ?' with params [2]:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`flow_db_pits_doc_manager`.`pits_docmanager_domain_model_role_role_accesspoints_join`, CONSTRAINT `FK_54B164455C544054` FOREIGN KEY (`docmanager_role`) REFERENCES `pits_docmanager_domain_model`)
>
> #23000: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`flow_db_pits_doc_manager`.`pits_docmanager_domain_model_role_role_accesspoints_join`, CONSTRAINT `FK_54B164455C544054` FOREIGN KEY (`docmanager_role`) REFERENCES `pits_docmanager_domain_model\`)

And in my entities i have
(role.php)

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<\Pits\DocManager\Domain\Model\AccessPoint> $role_accessPoints
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Pits\DocManager\Domain\Model\AccessPoint",cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_accesspoints",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="access_point_id",referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id",referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
protected $role_accessPoints;
```

and on the other file (accesspoints.php)

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<\Pits\DocManager\Domain\Model\Role> $accessPoint_roles
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Pits\DocManager\Domain\Model\Role",cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $accessPoint_roles;
```

even tho i have the cascade option set in the property am still not able to remove that entry.

Edit: What i am trying to achieve is that..

Consider i have 2 models (roles and accesspoints). if i delete a role, i need to be able to delete that role and the corresponding data related to that in the join table (and want to keep the data in accesspoints untouched)

Edit 2: Fixed (removed all the options from the cascade param and it worked)

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<\Pits\DocManager\Domain\Model\AccessPoint> $role_accessPoints
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Pits\DocManager\Domain\Model\AccessPoint",cascade={})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_accesspoints",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="access_point_id",referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id",referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
protected $role_accessPoints;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will automaticaly remove enries from mm table on deletion result

```
/**
 * Result organisation reletion(in Result model)
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<\WIND\Alertregistration\Domain\Model\Organization>
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(cascade={})
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="cascade")})
 */
protected $resultOrgRelation;
```